# Downloading google repository - url not found

Tags: android, repository

> Fetching https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
>   Validate XML Parse XML Fetched Add-ons List successfully Fetching URL:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml Validate
>   XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml Parse
>   XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
>   Found SDK Platform Android 7.1.1, API 25, revision 1   Found SDK
>   Platform Android 7.0, API 24, revision 2   Found SDK Platform Android
>   6.0, API 23, revision 3   Found SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2   Found SDK Platform Android 5.0.1, API 21, revision 2
>   Found SDK Platform Android 4.4W.2, API 20, revision 2   Found SDK
>   Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 4   Found SDK Platform
>   Android 4.3.1, API 18, revision 3   Found SDK Platform Android 4.2.2,
>   API 17, revision 3   Found SDK Platform Android 4.1.2, API 16,
>   revision 5   Found SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 5
>   Found SDK Platform Android 4.0, API 14, revision 4   Found SDK
>   Platform Android 3.2, API 13, revision 1   Found SDK Platform Android
>   3.1, API 12, revision 3   Found SDK Platform Android 3.0, API 11, revision 2   Found SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2
>   Found SDK Platform Android 2.3.1, API 9, revision 2   Found SDK
>   Platform Android 2.2, API 8, revision 3   Found SDK Platform Android
>   2.1, API 7, revision 3   Found SDK Platform Android 2.0.1, API 6, revision 1 (Obsolete)   Found SDK Platform Android 2.0, API 5,
>   revision 1 (Obsolete)   Found SDK Platform Android 1.6, API 4,
>   revision 3 (Obsolete)   Found SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3,
>   revision 4 (Obsolete)   Found SDK Platform Android 1.1, API 2,
>   revision 1 (Obsolete)   Found Sources for Android SDK, API 24,
>   revision 1   Found Sources for Android SDK, API 23, revision 1   Found
>   Sources for Android SDK, API 22, revision 1   Found Sources for
>   Android SDK, API 21, revision 1   Found Sources for Android SDK, API
>   20, revision 1   Found Sources for Android SDK, API 19, revision 2
>   Found Sources for Android SDK, API 18, revision 1   Found Sources for
>   Android SDK, API 17, revision 1   Found Sources for Android SDK, API
>   16, revision 2   Found Sources for Android SDK, API 15, revision 2
>   Found Sources for Android SDK, API 14, revision 1 (Obsolete)   Found
>   Android SDK Build-tools, revision 25   Found Android SDK Build-tools,
>   revision 24.0.3   Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 24.0.2
>   Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 24.0.1   Found Android SDK
>   Build-tools, revision 24   Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision
>   23.0.2   Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.3   Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.1   Found Android SDK
>   Build-tools, revision 23 (Obsolete)   Found Android SDK Build-tools,
>   revision 22.0.1   Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 22
>   (Obsolete)   Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1.2   Found
>   Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1.1 (Obsolete)   Found Android
>   SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1 (Obsolete)   Found Android SDK
>   Build-tools, revision 21.0.2 (Obsolete)   Found Android SDK
>   Build-tools, revision 21.0.1 (Obsolete)   Found Android SDK
>   Build-tools, revision 21 (Obsolete)   Found Android SDK Build-tools,
>   revision 20   Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.1   Found
>   Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.3 (Obsolete)   Found Android
>   SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.2 (Obsolete)   Found Android SDK
>   Build-tools, revision 19.0.1 (Obsolete)   Found Android SDK
>   Build-tools, revision 19 (Obsolete)   Found Android SDK Build-tools,
>   revision 18.1.1 (Obsolete)   Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision
>   18.1 (Obsolete)   Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.0.1 (Obsolete)   Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 17 (Obsolete)
>   Found Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 25   Found Android SDK
>   Tools, revision 25.2.2   Found Documentation for Android SDK, API 24,
>   revision 1 Fetching URL:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml Validate XML:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml Parse XML:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml   Found Google
>   APIs, Android API 3, revision 3 (Obsolete)   Found Google APIs,
>   Android API 4, revision 2 (Obsolete)   Found Google APIs, Android API
>   5, revision 1 (Obsolete)   Found Google APIs, Android API 6, revision
>   1 (Obsolete)   Found Google APIs, Android API 7, revision 1 (Obsolete)
>   Found Google APIs, Android API 8, revision 2 (Obsolete)   Found Google
>   APIs, Android API 9, revision 2 (Obsolete)   Found Google APIs,
>   Android API 10, revision 2 (Obsolete)   Found Google APIs, Android API
>   11, revision 1 (Obsolete)   Found Google APIs, Android API 12,
>   revision 1 (Obsolete)   Found Google APIs, Android API 13, revision 1
>   (Obsolete)   Found Google APIs, Android API 14, revision 2 (Obsolete) 
>   Found Google APIs, Android API 15, revision 3   Found Google APIs,
>   Android API 16, revision 4   Found Google APIs, Android API 17,
>   revision 4   Found Google APIs, Android API 18, revision 4   Found
>   Google APIs, Android API 19, revision 20   Found Google APIs, Android
>   API 24, revision 1   Found Google APIs, Android API 21, revision 1
>   Found Google APIs, Android API 22, revision 1   Found Google APIs,
>   Android API 23, revision 1   Found Google TV Addon, Android API 12,
>   revision 2 (Obsolete)   Found Google TV Addon, Android API 13,
>   revision 1 (Obsolete)   Found Android Support Repository, revision 39 
>   Found Android Support Library, revision 23.2.1 (Obsolete)   Found
>   Google Repository, revision 37   Found Google Play Licensing Library,
>   revision 1   Found Google Play APK Expansion library, revision 1
>   Found Google Play services for Froyo, revision 12 (Obsolete)   Found
>   Google Play services, revision 37   Found Google USB Driver, revision
>   11   Found Google Play Billing Library, revision 5   Found Google
>   AdMob Ads SDK, revision 11 (Obsolete)   Found Google Analytics App
>   Tracking SDK, revision 3 (Obsolete)   Found Google Web Driver,
>   revision 2   Found Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library,
>   revision 3 (Obsolete)   Found Android Auto API Simulators, revision 1 
>   Found Android Auto Desktop Head Unit emulator, revision 1.1 Fetching
>   URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml Validate
>   XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml Parse
>   XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
>   Found Glass Development Kit Preview, Android API 19, revision 11
>   Fetching URL:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
>   Validate XML:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml Parse
>   XML:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
>   Found Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer), revision 6.0.3 
>   Found Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer), revision 6.0.4
>   Fetching URL:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
>   Validate XML:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
>   Parse XML:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
>   Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 14, revision 2   Found
>   ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 15, revision 3   Found ARM EABI
>   v7a System Image, Android API 16, revision 4   Found ARM EABI v7a
>   System Image, Android API 17, revision 3   Found ARM EABI v7a System
>   Image, Android API 18, revision 3   Found ARM EABI v7a System Image,
>   Android API 19, revision 3   Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android
>   API 21, revision 3   Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 22,
>   revision 1   Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 23, revision
>   3   Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 24, revision 7
>   Found ARM 64 v8a System Image, Android API 24, revision 7   Found MIPS
>   System Image, Android API 15, revision 1   Found MIPS System Image,
>   Android API 16, revision 1   Found MIPS System Image, Android API 17,
>   revision 1   Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 10,
>   revision 3   Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 15,
>   revision 2   Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 16,
>   revision 2   Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 17,
>   revision 2   Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 18,
>   revision 2   Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 19,
>   revision 5   Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 21,
>   revision 4   Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 22,
>   revision 5   Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23,
>   revision 9   Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 24,
>   revision 7   Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android
>   API 25, revision 2   Found Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API
>   21, revision 4   Found Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 22,
>   revision 5   Found Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 23,
>   revision 9   Found Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 24,
>   revision 7   Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android
>   API 25, revision 2 Fetching URL:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
>   Validate XML:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
>   Parse XML:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
>   Found Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 20, revision
>   4   Found Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 20,
>   revision 4   Found Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API
>   21, revision 3   Found Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image,
>   Android API 21, revision 3   Found Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System
>   Image, Android API 22, revision 7   Found Android Wear Intel x86 Atom
>   System Image, Android API 22, revision 7   Found Android Wear ARM EABI
>   v7a System Image, Android API 23, revision 6   Found Android Wear
>   Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23, revision 6   Found
>   Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 24, revision 2
>   Found Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 24,
>   revision 2 Fetching URL:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
>   Validate XML:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
>   Parse XML:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
>   Found Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 21, revision
>   3   Found Android TV ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 21,
>   revision 3   Found Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API
>   22, revision 3   Found Android TV ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android
>   API 22, revision 1   Found Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image,
>   Android API 23, revision 6   Found Android TV ARM EABI v7a System
>   Image, Android API 23, revision 3   Found Android TV Intel x86 Atom
>   System Image, Android API 24, revision 7   Found Android TV Intel x86
>   Atom System Image, Android API 25, revision 1 Fetching URL:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
>   Validate XML:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
>   Parse XML:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
>   Found Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 10, revision
>   5   Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 10,
>   revision 5   Found Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API
>   15, revision 5   Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image,
>   Android API 15, revision 5   Found Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System
>   Image, Android API 16, revision 5   Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
>   System Image, Android API 16, revision 5   Found Google APIs ARM EABI
>   v7a System Image, Android API 17, revision 5   Found Google APIs Intel
>   x86 Atom System Image, Android API 17, revision 5   Found Google APIs
>   ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 18, revision 5   Found Google
>   APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 18, revision 5   Found
>   Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 19, revision 24
>   Found Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 19, revision
>   24   Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 21,
>   revision 16   Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image,
>   Android API 21, revision 16   Found Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System
>   Image, Android API 21, revision 16   Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
>   System Image, Android API 22, revision 10   Found Google APIs ARM EABI
>   v7a System Image, Android API 22, revision 10   Found Google APIs
>   Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 22, revision 10   Found
>   Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23, revision 17
>   Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 23,
>   revision 17   Found Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API
>   23, revision 17   Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image,
>   Android API 24, revision 8   Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64
>   System Image, Android API 24, revision 8   Found Google APIs ARM EABI
>   v7a System Image, Android API 24, revision 8   Found Google APIs ARM
>   64 v8a System Image, Android API 24, revision 8 Done loading packages.
>   Fetching https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
>   Validate XML Parse XML Fetched Add-ons List successfully Fetching URL:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml Validate
>   XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml Parse
>   XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
>   Found SDK Platform Android 7.1.1, API 25, revision 1   Found SDK
>   Platform Android 7.0, API 24, revision 2   Found SDK Platform Android
>   6.0, API 23, revision 3   Found SDK Platform Android 5.1.1, API 22, revision 2   Found SDK Platform Android 5.0.1, API 21, revision 2
>   Found SDK Platform Android 4.4W.2, API 20, revision 2   Found SDK
>   Platform Android 4.4.2, API 19, revision 4   Found SDK Platform
>   Android 4.3.1, API 18, revision 3   Found SDK Platform Android 4.2.2,
>   API 17, revision 3   Found SDK Platform Android 4.1.2, API 16,
>   revision 5   Found SDK Platform Android 4.0.3, API 15, revision 5
>   Found SDK Platform Android 4.0, API 14, revision 4   Found SDK
>   Platform Android 3.2, API 13, revision 1   Found SDK Platform Android
>   3.1, API 12, revision 3   Found SDK Platform Android 3.0, API 11, revision 2   Found SDK Platform Android 2.3.3, API 10, revision 2
>   Found SDK Platform Android 2.3.1, API 9, revision 2   Found SDK
>   Platform Android 2.2, API 8, revision 3   Found SDK Platform Android
>   2.1, API 7, revision 3   Found SDK Platform Android 2.0.1, API 6, revision 1 (Obsolete)   Found SDK Platform Android 2.0, API 5,
>   revision 1 (Obsolete)   Found SDK Platform Android 1.6, API 4,
>   revision 3 (Obsolete)   Found SDK Platform Android 1.5, API 3,
>   revision 4 (Obsolete)   Found SDK Platform Android 1.1, API 2,
>   revision 1 (Obsolete)   Found Sources for Android SDK, API 24,
>   revision 1   Found Sources for Android SDK, API 23, revision 1   Found
>   Sources for Android SDK, API 22, revision 1   Found Sources for
>   Android SDK, API 21, revision 1   Found Sources for Android SDK, API
>   20, revision 1   Found Sources for Android SDK, API 19, revision 2
>   Found Sources for Android SDK, API 18, revision 1   Found Sources for
>   Android SDK, API 17, revision 1   Found Sources for Android SDK, API
>   16, revision 2   Found Sources for Android SDK, API 15, revision 2
>   Found Sources for Android SDK, API 14, revision 1 (Obsolete)   Found
>   Android SDK Build-tools, revision 25   Found Android SDK Build-tools,
>   revision 24.0.3   Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 24.0.2
>   Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 24.0.1   Found Android SDK
>   Build-tools, revision 24   Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision
>   23.0.2   Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.3   Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.1   Found Android SDK
>   Build-tools, revision 23 (Obsolete)   Found Android SDK Build-tools,
>   revision 22.0.1   Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 22
>   (Obsolete)   Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1.2   Found
>   Android SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1.1 (Obsolete)   Found Android
>   SDK Build-tools, revision 21.1 (Obsolete)   Found Android SDK
>   Build-tools, revision 21.0.2 (Obsolete)   Found Android SDK
>   Build-tools, revision 21.0.1 (Obsolete)   Found Android SDK
>   Build-tools, revision 21 (Obsolete)   Found Android SDK Build-tools,
>   revision 20   Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.1   Found
>   Android SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.3 (Obsolete)   Found Android
>   SDK Build-tools, revision 19.0.2 (Obsolete)   Found Android SDK
>   Build-tools, revision 19.0.1 (Obsolete)   Found Android SDK
>   Build-tools, revision 19 (Obsolete)   Found Android SDK Build-tools,
>   revision 18.1.1 (Obsolete)   Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision
>   18.1 (Obsolete)   Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 18.0.1 (Obsolete)   Found Android SDK Build-tools, revision 17 (Obsolete)
>   Found Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 25   Found Android SDK
>   Tools, revision 25.2.2   Found Documentation for Android SDK, API 24,
>   revision 1 Fetching URL:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml Validate XML:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml Parse XML:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml   Found Google
>   APIs, Android API 3, revision 3 (Obsolete)   Found Google APIs,
>   Android API 4, revision 2 (Obsolete)   Found Google APIs, Android API
>   5, revision 1 (Obsolete)   Found Google APIs, Android API 6, revision
>   1 (Obsolete)   Found Google APIs, Android API 7, revision 1 (Obsolete)
>   Found Google APIs, Android API 8, revision 2 (Obsolete)   Found Google
>   APIs, Android API 9, revision 2 (Obsolete)   Found Google APIs,
>   Android API 10, revision 2 (Obsolete)   Found Google APIs, Android API
>   11, revision 1 (Obsolete)   Found Google APIs, Android API 12,
>   revision 1 (Obsolete)   Found Google APIs, Android API 13, revision 1
>   (Obsolete)   Found Google APIs, Android API 14, revision 2 (Obsolete) 
>   Found Google APIs, Android API 15, revision 3   Found Google APIs,
>   Android API 16, revision 4   Found Google APIs, Android API 17,
>   revision 4   Found Google APIs, Android API 18, revision 4   Found
>   Google APIs, Android API 19, revision 20   Found Google APIs, Android
>   API 24, revision 1   Found Google APIs, Android API 21, revision 1
>   Found Google APIs, Android API 22, revision 1   Found Google APIs,
>   Android API 23, revision 1   Found Google TV Addon, Android API 12,
>   revision 2 (Obsolete)   Found Google TV Addon, Android API 13,
>   revision 1 (Obsolete)   Found Android Support Repository, revision 39 
>   Found Android Support Library, revision 23.2.1 (Obsolete)   Found
>   Google Repository, revision 37   Found Google Play Licensing Library,
>   revision 1   Found Google Play APK Expansion library, revision 1
>   Found Google Play services for Froyo, revision 12 (Obsolete)   Found
>   Google Play services, revision 37   Found Google USB Driver, revision
>   11   Found Google Play Billing Library, revision 5   Found Google
>   AdMob Ads SDK, revision 11 (Obsolete)   Found Google Analytics App
>   Tracking SDK, revision 3 (Obsolete)   Found Google Web Driver,
>   revision 2   Found Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library,
>   revision 3 (Obsolete)   Found Android Auto API Simulators, revision 1 
>   Found Android Auto Desktop Head Unit emulator, revision 1.1 Fetching
>   URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml Validate
>   XML: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml Parse
>   XML:    https://dl.google.com/android/repository/glass/addon.xml
>   Found Glass Development Kit Preview, Android API 19, revision 11
>   Fetching URL:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
>   Validate XML:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml Parse
>   XML:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon.xml
>   Found Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer), revision 6.0.3 
>   Found Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer), revision 6.0.4
>   Fetching URL:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
>   Validate XML:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
>   Parse XML:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
>   Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 14, revision 2   Found
>   ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 15, revision 3   Found ARM EABI
>   v7a System Image, Android API 16, revision 4   Found ARM EABI v7a
>   System Image, Android API 17, revision 3   Found ARM EABI v7a System
>   Image, Android API 18, revision 3   Found ARM EABI v7a System Image,
>   Android API 19, revision 3   Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android
>   API 21, revision 3   Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 22,
>   revision 1   Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 23, revision
>   3   Found ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 24, revision 7
>   Found ARM 64 v8a System Image, Android API 24, revision 7   Found MIPS
>   System Image, Android API 15, revision 1   Found MIPS System Image,
>   Android API 16, revision 1   Found MIPS System Image, Android API 17,
>   revision 1   Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 10,
>   revision 3   Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 15,
>   revision 2   Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 16,
>   revision 2   Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 17,
>   revision 2   Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 18,
>   revision 2   Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 19,
>   revision 5   Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 21,
>   revision 4   Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 22,
>   revision 5   Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23,
>   revision 9   Found Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 24,
>   revision 7   Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android
>   API 25, revision 2   Found Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API
>   21, revision 4   Found Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 22,
>   revision 5   Found Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 23,
>   revision 9   Found Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 24,
>   revision 7   Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android
>   API 25, revision 2 Fetching URL:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
>   Validate XML:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
>   Parse XML:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-wear/sys-img.xml
>   Found Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 20, revision
>   4   Found Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 20,
>   revision 4   Found Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API
>   21, revision 3   Found Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image,
>   Android API 21, revision 3   Found Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System
>   Image, Android API 22, revision 7   Found Android Wear Intel x86 Atom
>   System Image, Android API 22, revision 7   Found Android Wear ARM EABI
>   v7a System Image, Android API 23, revision 6   Found Android Wear
>   Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23, revision 6   Found
>   Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 24, revision 2
>   Found Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 24,
>   revision 2 Fetching URL:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
>   Validate XML:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
>   Parse XML:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android-tv/sys-img.xml
>   Found Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 21, revision
>   3   Found Android TV ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 21,
>   revision 3   Found Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API
>   22, revision 3   Found Android TV ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android
>   API 22, revision 1   Found Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image,
>   Android API 23, revision 6   Found Android TV ARM EABI v7a System
>   Image, Android API 23, revision 3   Found Android TV Intel x86 Atom
>   System Image, Android API 24, revision 7   Found Android TV Intel x86
>   Atom System Image, Android API 25, revision 1 Fetching URL:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
>   Validate XML:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
>   Parse XML:
>   https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
>   Found Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 10, revision
>   5   Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 10,
>   revision 5   Found Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API
>   15, revision 5   Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image,
>   Android API 15, revision 5   Found Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System
>   Image, Android API 16, revision 5   Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
>   System Image, Android API 16, revision 5   Found Google APIs ARM EABI
>   v7a System Image, Android API 17, revision 5   Found Google APIs Intel
>   x86 Atom System Image, Android API 17, revision 5   Found Google APIs
>   ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 18, revision 5   Found Google
>   APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 18, revision 5   Found
>   Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 19, revision 24
>   Found Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 19, revision
>   24   Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 21,
>   revision 16   Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image,
>   Android API 21, revision 16   Found Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System
>   Image, Android API 21, revision 16   Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
>   System Image, Android API 22, revision 10   Found Google APIs ARM EABI
>   v7a System Image, Android API 22, revision 10   Found Google APIs
>   Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 22, revision 10   Found
>   Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23, revision 17
>   Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 23,
>   revision 17   Found Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API
>   23, revision 17   Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image,
>   Android API 24, revision 8   Found Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64
>   System Image, Android API 24, revision 8   Found Google APIs ARM EABI
>   v7a System Image, Android API 24, revision 8   Found Google APIs ARM
>   64 v8a System Image, Android API 24, revision 8 Done loading packages.
>   Preparing to install archives Downloading Google Repository, revision
>   37 Download interrupted: URL not found. Done. Nothing was installed.

Thats what I get, its very strange.As everything else in sdk manager was downloaded, apart from repository!Am using macbook pro.

Comment: I've been having the same problem today. SDK manager can download everything except the "Google Repository". Says URL not found.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue on one device (which reports revision 37 as the latest release) but not on another (which reports revision 36 as the latest).